# After shipping address is saved in checkout redirect customer to another url if shipping country is

Tags: shipping, redirect, countries

After shipping adress is saved in checkout, redirect customer to another url if shipping country is for example US where could I do it?
I would use

```
if($this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getCountry() =='US'){
redirect...
}
```

How could I do it ? thank you

Comment: I think you need to add conditions in checkout.js and then redirect the customer as per your need

Comment: can i use here a js and how?